# what force pump is needed to power

Tags: homework-and-exercises, fluid-dynamics, pressure, water

[image]
[image]

Im studying design have not got a good grasp on maths, but understand the working principles of pressure and water! my problem hopefully has included all necessary info in the image.

Please help.

all the best 
Conor

Comment: I don't understand what is "4 cm depth" vs the "30 cm" dimension shown in your diagram. Could you describe the problem in terms of "how high you lift the water"? Because the weight (mass x 10) times the height (in meters) divided by the time (3 minutes) is a good measure of the power (Watt) needed. But I can't figure that from your diagram.

Comment: total hieght water needs to be raised is 55cm.Size of container length 30cm breath 9cm width 4cm

Comment: also its the power of the pump i need are pumps measured in watts?

Comment: $\frac{mgh}{t} = p$ usually works as an approximate.

Comment: hieght is 55cm. mass of water is 12kg

Comment: what dose mgh mean?

Comment: p=2.156 watts=2.2 what air pump do i need?

Comment: Not sure how you go from "1.2 liter" to "12 kg". 1 liter = 1 kg. I think you are overestimating the power needed.

Comment: Ah - you are using t=3, but it is minutes (180 seconds). And the mass is 1.2 kg (weight 12 Newton).

Answer (score 0):

If you raise 1.2 liter of water (mass 1.2 kg) by 55 cm (h) in 3 minutes (t) against a gravitational acceleration $g$ of 9.81 m/s<sup>2</sup>, the average power needed is

$$\frac{m\cdot g\cdot h}{t} = \frac{1.2\cdot 9.81 \cdot 0.55}{180} < 40 \mathrm{\;mW}$$.

But if the depth of your water is 30 cm, then *on average* the water needs to be raised just 40 cm, not 55 (depending on how you came up with the number 55) - in which case you need to adjust the above.

Either way, it would be a pretty low power pump.